# Postgres - granting all permissions, but still denied on tables

Tags: postgresql

I have a DB in Postgres that i administrate with the admin user and i want to create a schema and tables for an application user.

I am creating the schema and the app user with the admin user and then i grant:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_schema to my_user;
```

Then i create my tables inside my_schema, but when i try to access them with my_user i get permission denied:

> ERROR permission denied for table my_table

Is there a way to solve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GRANT … ON ALL TABLES` does not include *future* tables. You were granting permissions on all tables currently in the schema, then you were creating new tables. Those new tables won't have any permissions granted to `my_user`.

You can either

- move the `GRANT … ON ALL TABLES` statement *after* the creation of the tables on which you want to grant the privileges, or
- [change the default privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) that will be applied to new objects (i.e. tables):

  ```
  ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE admin_user IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLES TO my_user;
  ```

  This will automatically `GRANT` the specified privileges to `my_user` on any new table that `admin_user` will create.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have mentioned privileges for your 'my_user'. You need to have USAGE privilege.

What you need to do in order to successfully retrieve data from tables in schema 'my_schema'. If I understand your question correctly. You should follow this:

1. create schema my_schema; -- create tables if not already exists
2. create user my_user; -- set password as per your security recommendation
3. grant usage on schema my_schema to my_user;
4. GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_schema to my_user;

Comment: Thank you! What i was trying to do is to give those permissions on any tables that are and will be created in the schema. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

With this: GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_schema to my_user;

You only grant permissions for tables that already exists.

If you want to ensure that your user get mentioned privileges also in future when new table will be created:

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLES to my_user;

*this means that every table that will be created in schema my_schema will be automatically granted to my_user with (select,insert,update,delete) privilege.